# Showing Convergence in $L^p$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a finite measure space and $1\le p<\infty$ and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^p(X)$ such that coverge to $f$ in $L^p(X)$  . If there exists constant $K$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and every $x\in X$ $$|f_n(x)|\le K $$ then for every $1\le r<\infty$ we have $$||f_n-f||_{r} \to 0 $$ which $|| \ .||_p $ is $ L^p $ norm.

Comment: $f_n\to f$ in which topology? (e.g. $L^p$, a.e., etc. - the text is missing this)

Comment: @ Milly : $L^p$

Comment: ok, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the conclusion is not true, so there $\exists r, \geq 1$ $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $\|f_{n_k} - f\|_r \geq \epsilon$.

But $f_{n_k}$ converges in $L^p$ to $f$, so its has a sub-subsquence $\{f_{n_{k_l}}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_{k_l}}\}$ converges to $f$ almost surely.

Then by dominated convergence, we get $f_{n_{k_l}}$ conveges in $L^r$ to $f$, which is contradictory with $\|f_{n_k} - f\|_r \geq \epsilon$.

So it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ and $X$ has finite measure, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^q$ for any $1\leq q\leq p$.

For $p<r<+\infty$, you know that $|f_n(x)|\leq K$ uniformly. Convergence in $L^p$ gives convergence a.e. along subsequence $f_{n_k}\to f$, and by dominated convergence
$f_{n_k}\to f$ in $L^r$. If there exists another sequence $f_{m_k}\to g\neq f$ in $L^r$, then (since $r>p$) you have $f_{m_r}\to g\neq f$ in $L^p$, contradicting the hypothesis $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

Comment: $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ does not mean $f_n$ will converge to another function $g$, $f_n$ can simply has no limit

Comment: The sequence $f_{m_k}$ has subsequence with a.e. limit (since it is Cauchy in $L^p$), hence by dominated convergence such subsequence has $L^r$ limit. Thus (upon relabeling) we can call such subsequence $f_{m_k}$.

Comment: I agree with your comment. But negation of $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^r$ is that $f_n$ has a subsequence that does not converge to $f$ in $L^r$. You said this subsequence has a sub-subsequence which converge to $f$(almost surly and in $L^r$). But having a subsubsequence which converges does not mean the subsequence itself converges, no?

Comment: Agree. It is possible to make the assertion stronger: for any subsequence $f_{n_h}$ not converging to $f$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(f_{n_h})\cap \{g:\|g-f\|_{L^p}\geq \delta\}$ is infinite (since if such delta does not exist, then $f_{n_h}$ is a a Cauchy converging to $f$). The argument before allows to extract from $(f_{n_h})\cap \{g:\|g-f\|_{L^p}\geq \delta\}$ a sequence converging to $f$.

Comment: Yeah, I argued like this in my answer too :)